# What's difference between "tar -cSF - | tar xvf -" and "cp -R"

Tags: linux, command-line

For example,

```
tar -cSf - -C /mnt/abc . | tar xvf - -C /mnt/def
```

isn't this the same as:

```
cp -RT /mnt/abc /mnt/def
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are mostly the same, in that they will both make a copy of a directory tree. They differ in their treatment of metadata.

`tar cf - … | tar xf - …` marshals all data through tar format. This means any metadata that cannot be represented in tar format is lost. There are several variants of the tar format, so exactly what is lost will depend on the tar implementation. Here are a few limitations of current GNU tar (some of them may be overcome by switching to a different tar format):

- There may be a limit on such things as file name length (255 bytes are ok, I don't know the exact limit), user and group IDs (up to 65535 is ok), file sizes (up to 8GB is ok), etc.
- For example, files whose path is more than 100 characters long and with at least two hard links in the tree being copied will not be copied correctly (I forget exactly what the behavior is).
- Access control lists will not be replicated.
- Timestamps will only be precise to the nearest second.

`cp -RT` doesn't preserve a lot of metadata. In particular, it won't preserve file times and ownership. On the other hand, with GNU cp, **`cp -a`** will preserve pretty much all metadata (I haven't been able to fault it, except maybe on directory access times in corner cases and subsecond timestamps on some operating systems).

Answer (score 2):

`cp` will copy character by character.  Using the kernel pipes support, we could copy files block by block.  The reason I've used tar in the past has been for network transfers like the following:

```
tar czv ListOfFiles | ssh remote.box.com tar xz -C /home/user/PathToCopy
```

See [this link](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/TIP_Fast_Copy) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

with the tar-copy you can:

- put other programs between the pipes (eg. pv to measure copy speed)
- or netcat to transfer it to another machine
- you can use --include and --exclude to avoid copying some files or to include only certain files

Answer (score 0):

tar will handle more things appropriately, such as sparse files, permissions, and links.

Comment: But with `cp -a`, GNU cp will do a much better job than tar.

Answer (score 0):

You `cp` command won't preserve timestamps, you need to add `-p` switch. `-d` will be also needed to preserve symbolic links.